# Why the same configuration network in caffe and pytorch behaves so differently?

Tags: caffe, pytorch, nvidia-digits

the code in pytorch is [here](https://github.com/chengyangfu/pytorch-vgg-cifar10), I only used the **vgg19** arch.

In order to make the cifar10 dataset preprocessed same in caffe and pytorch, I remove all the transforms in [`main.py`](https://github.com/chengyangfu/pytorch-vgg-cifar10/blob/master/main.py#L91) but `toTensor()`. I found the cifar10 dataset's range is [0,1] in pytorch, but caffe is [0,255], so I scale 1/255 below. Any extra preprocessing is canceled to make things easier.

here is my caffe net definition prototxt:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00392156862745
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/home/snk/Documents/digits-jobs/20180106-135745-4cac/train_db"
    batch_size: 128
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00392156862745
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/home/snk/Documents/digits-jobs/20180106-135745-4cac/val_db"
    batch_size: 128
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1_1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1_1"
  top: "conv1_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv1_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv1_1"
  top: "conv1_2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1_2"
  top: "conv1_2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1_2"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2_1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2_1"
  top: "conv2_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv2_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv2_1"
  top: "conv2_2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2_2"
  top: "conv2_2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2_2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv3_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv3_1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3_1"
  top: "conv3_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv3_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3_1"
  top: "conv3_2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3_2"
  top: "conv3_2"
}
layer {
  name: "conv3_3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3_2"
  top: "conv3_3"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3_3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3_3"
  top: "conv3_3"
}
layer {
  name: "conv3_4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3_3"
  top: "conv3_4"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3_4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3_4"
  top: "conv3_4"
}
layer {
  name: "pool3"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv3_4"
  top: "pool3"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv4_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool3"
  top: "conv4_1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4_1"
  top: "conv4_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv4_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv4_1"
  top: "conv4_2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4_2"
  top: "conv4_2"
}
layer {
  name: "conv4_3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv4_2"
  top: "conv4_3"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4_3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4_3"
  top: "conv4_3"
}
layer {
  name: "conv4_4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv4_3"
  top: "conv4_4"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4_4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4_4"
  top: "conv4_4"
}
layer {
  name: "pool4"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv4_4"
  top: "pool4"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv5_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool4"
  top: "conv5_1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5_1"
  top: "conv5_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv5_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv5_1"
  top: "conv5_2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5_2"
  top: "conv5_2"
}
layer {
  name: "conv5_3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv5_2"
  top: "conv5_3"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5_3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5_3"
  top: "conv5_3"
}
layer {
  name: "conv5_4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv5_3"
  top: "conv5_4"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5_4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5_4"
  top: "conv5_4"
}
layer {
  name: "pool5"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv5_4"
  top: "pool5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "drop6"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "drop_pool5"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc6"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "drop_pool5"
  top: "fc6"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 512
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
}
layer {
  name: "drop7"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc7"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc7"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 512
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu7"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
}
layer {
  name: "fc8"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc8"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 10
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "acc"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

Here is my solver.prototxt

```
test_iter: 79
test_interval: 391
base_lr: 0.05
display: 40
max_iter: 117300
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.5
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
stepsize: 11730
snapshot: 3910
snapshot_prefix: "snapshot"
solver_mode: GPU
net: "train_val.prototxt"
solver_type: SGD
```

The fact is pytorch can train the model at a very quick speed, the acc after one epoch is about 20%, but in caffe the loss is always around 2.3XXX (about -log(0.1), random guess loss), I suspect it was because the different weight initialization, so I changed caffe's [`filler.hpp`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/filler.hpp#L160)'s xavier to 'efficient backprop'(i.e U(-std, std), std=1/(sqrt(fan_in))), but it didn't work.

Now, the only difference is the bias initialization method, in pytorch it uses the weight's fan_in, but in caffe I think it uses the output_num as fan_in (because its shape is [1,N], N is the number of output neurons, and in filler.hpp it use blob.count() / blob.num() as fan_in for xavier ).

Who can help me ? I think if all the configuration is the same, the training process is almost the same ,but it breaked my opinion.